# Constructing a triangle given an angle, the side opposed to this angle, and the median to the given side.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

I came across the following problem in my Euclidean Geometry text:

> Construct a triangle having given an angle, the side opposed to this angle, and the median to the given side.

I have tried solving this problem using method of loci, with Locus 1 being the circumcircle of the sought for triangle and Locus 2 being the circle of radius of the given  median. However I don't know how to start this construction.

Comment: To construct the circumcircle draw a ray $AP$ at point $A$ of given side $AB$ forming an angle $\angle PAB$ equal to given angle $\alpha$. Circumcenter is then  the intersection of the perpendicular at $A$ to $AP$ and the perpendicular bisector of $AB$.

Answer (score 1):

If the given angle is acute: To construct the circumscribed circle, observe that the inscribed angle is half of the central angle (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle) for the terms and a picture). So you can start with your given side, construct an isosceles triangle with double the given angle opposite that side, and the newly constructed vertex of this triangle will be the center of the circumscribed circle you are looking for.

If the given angle is obtuse: Use the supplementary angle of the given angle to construct the isosceles triangle. The  new vertex you construct is the center of the circumscribed triangle in this case.

When completing the construction you need to be mindful of which of these two cases you are in: the side you start with divides the circumcircle into two arcs; the third vertex of your triangle will lie on the same side as the center (i.e. on the longer arc) if the angle was acute, and on the opposite side (i.e. on the shorter arc) if it was obtuse.

If the angle just happened to be a right angle, then the center of the circumscribed circle is the midpoint of the given side (and you will have infinite number of solutions if the median length was half the size of the given side, the third vertex  being anywhere on the circumcircle; or no solution if it was not).

Comment: This requires a slight modification when the given angle is obtuse.  In such a case the apex angle of the isosceles triangle must be twice the _supplement_ of the given angle.  With that, an obtuse-angle vertex would have the given side passing between it and the center, while an acute-angle vertex would have the side not in-between.  Can you incorporate these differences into the answer?

Comment: @OscarLanzi Sure.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I found this method experimentally. I am still looking for some theorem to prove following statement:

For a certain measure of BC which is the base of triangle ABC and radius of a circle center O at mid point of BC, with radius equal to measure of median $m_a$ we have:

$\angle BAC - \angle BPO= constant$

In figure AC||PO is the condition of above relation.

We use this fact to construct a triangle it's base, median and angle $\alpha $ opposite to base is given:

Draw a circle center on midpoint O of base BC. Draw PO and PB such that:

$\angle BPO=\frac{\alpha}2$

Draw a line from C parallel with PO, it intersect the circle at A. Connect A to B , The measure of  $\angle BAC$  will be:

$\angle BAC- \angle BPO=d$

Now to get $\angle BAC=\alpha$, construct $\angle BPC = \frac {\alpha}2 + d$ and draw a line from C parallel with PO to get vertex A.

In figure givens are $\alpha=40^o$, $BC=110 mm$ and $m_a=115 mm$

Answer (score 0):

See the picture below:
[image: Construction of triangle]

1. Draw segment AB and its middle point C.
2. Draw the perpendicular bisector g and angle ACC'.
3. Draw the  line i perpendicular to AC'.
4. Let D the intersection of g and i.
5. Draw the circle $\Lambda$ with center D and radius AD.
6. Draw the circle $\Gamma$ with center C and radius $l$ (the median length).
7. Let E and E' the intersections of $\Lambda$ and $\Gamma$.
8. Draw triangles ABE or ABE', solutions of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved by method of two loci. The procedure is given below.To begin, let us assume the triangle ABC has sides a, b and c, angles A, B and C and median AD, BE and CF. According to the problem we are given the following elements- A, a, AD.

1. Draw BC having length as a units.
2. Construct arc BC such that it subtends an angle of 2A at any point on it. This will be the first locus for the triangle's circumcircle.
3. Construct perpendicular bisector PQ of BC. Let PQ ∩ Arc BC = {O}.
4. Draw the circle having center O and radius OB. For simplified notation, i'll refer to it as C(O,R).
5. Let PQ ∩ BC = {M}. Taking M as center, draw a circle having center M and radius AD. I will refer to this circle as C(M,m).
6. Let C(M,m) ∩ C(O,R) = {A,A'}.
7. Complete triangle A(A')BC as desired.

Note:
Note that the above problem may have 2 solutions in a very general case.

Answer (score 0):

Angle between tangent and side being equal to that in the alternate segment is the circle property useful here. Given points A,B on x-axis ; set the given angle at B below tangent in CCW direction as shown and erect a perpendicular at B to obtain circle center F by intersection with the central median (Perp. bisector AB). Next, with middle point H and given median length HI draw a circular arc to find another point J satisfying both conditions.

$\angle {AFB} $ at center is seen to be double the given angle.

[image]